# Draggable Box Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

Exact code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>jQTest</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<style>
    #square {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:grey;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="square"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#square").draggable();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I've tried

- Moving the reference to the Google APIs toward the top and right above the script (where it currently is).  I've experienced two issues with jQuery where the code reference location caused the problem.
- I referenced a newer library in one try - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js.  Nothing either.  The instructors uses the one I list above this though, and I do see it working for him.
- [I built a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0rw13jn/), and it doesn't function there either.  Note that I use a more recent library in this.  Again, the instructor did this and I copied his code directly and then played around with it, so I don't see what I'm missing here.

Comment: Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashishbpatil1/g0rw13jn/3/)

Comment: @abpatil That does work, but what am I missing in the code?  I don't see any difference unless I'm missing a character or something.

Comment: 1. load jQuery lib. 2. load jquery ui lib. 3. call .draggable() inside a document ready function

Comment: @wpquestionz you should add both jquery and jquery UI. Check this [example](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Comment: @abpatil The combination of that and wrapping it in a function solved the issue.